# Android/Java - How to know what's the current value of DecimalFormat

Tags: java, android

I have a button and TextView.
In the TextView I'm showing a value of a float number, with two digits after the dot.

The button is taking by each press a 0.01 from the current float number (which is being shown at the TextView).

In order to do so I've used the next code -

```
        float hightCurrent =  Float.parseFloat(hightNum.getText().toString());
    hightCurrent -= 0.01;
      DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("##0.00");
       myFormatter.format(hightCurrent);

    if(myFormatter.equals("1.10")){
        Log.d("GOT", "Got in");

    }else{

    }


    hightNum.setText((myFormatter.format(hightCurrent)));
```

NOw as you can see I have an if statement. 
What I want to know is when the value is 1.10.

The thing is that when the value that being shown is 1.10 it sure don't get into the if statement.

So how can I make this code work? how can I know when the value is 1.10?

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: `String newCurrent=myFormatter.format(hightCurrent);` and check `newCurrent.equals("1.10")` ..Try it..

Comment: why do you try to compare the strings anyway? Just check if highCurrent == 1.1f

Comment: float newCurrent=myFormatter.format(hightCurrent); ---this is wrong you can't compare float to String!

Comment: See my comment once more..I've edited..

Comment: Did you try it @4this ???

Comment: I told you the same answer first.. @4this ..

Comment: I'll add that as my answer..kindly upvote my answer too..please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Assign `myFormatter.format(hightCurrent);` to a String variable
2. Compare the value of this var

Hence;

```
String str = myFormatter.format(hightCurrent);
if(str.equals("1.10")){
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`String newCurrent=myFormatter.format(hightCurrent);`

and check `newCurrent.equals("1.10")`

Try it.